# fatal error: Array index out of range in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

hello I have a Dynamic Prototype TableView. I have added 4 prototype cells. Three are static and one is dynamic. The problem is I am getting Array index out of range error. could you please check what went wrong. what should be the total number of rows should I assign

```
let NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS = 3
var labels = ["label1","label2","label3"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return labels.count+NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS



}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    var cell:  TestViewCell!

    print(indexPath.row)
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell


    }

    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
        //cell.cardSetName?.text = self.cardSetObject["name"] as String
        }

     if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
            //cell.cardSetName?.text = self.cardSetObject["name"] as String
        }




      if (indexPath.row >= 3) {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
        cell.testLabel.text = labels[indexPath.row] // return test rows as set in numberOfRowsInSection
    }

    return cell;
   }
```

Comment: FYI, Apple in their Swift documentation notes constants should be reversed camel case ..... not all caps. That's really a C thing only :/. use a switch case for your row checks as well, this will clean up your code.. a lot.

Comment: Still broken, the updated logic is trying to access indexes 3,4 and 5, which are out of bounds. Try `labels[indexPath.row - NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS]`. Also change `>= 3 to >= NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS`. Also what @TheCodingArt said about constant case

Comment: Also, I'd strongly advise you to make more effort to keep your indentation consistent - you just make it harder for yourself when you don't - all of your `if` should be indented at the same level - to someone scanning your code it looks like you have nested `ifs` when you don't

Comment: @RichTolley okay Thanks it worked. could you post your comment as an answer

Comment: You should accept and upvote @JulianKról's answer - his suggestion catches a detail about the `if` statement that I missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set that number of cells will be 6 and in labels array you have only 3 elements. Moreover in each condition you are assigning to cell but at the end of the method you are overwriting that assignment which is (I suppose) not your intention. Then you are trying to access element under the index that is out of bounds

Comment: sorry I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: Still same problem. In the last condition you are accessing elements at indexes 3, 4... in the array that has only 3 elements. This is why your app is crashing. Put the breakpoint and inspect the values, you will spot the issue

Comment: so what should I do ? well I have three static cells and rest of the cells will be dynamic. so meaning the 4th one. please could you tell how many rows should I define.

Comment: it looks like you want in the last condition have indexPath.row < labels.count+NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS - 1 && indexPath.row >=3 and access labels like labels[indexPath.row -  NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS]

Comment: Anyway you should start debugging your code yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

This is your ERROR!  You have no label with an index above 2. The line below tries to do to label[3] etc.

```
cell.testLabel.text = labels[indexPath.row]
```